# Git Sub-Modules in 1 Directory

Tags: git, git-submodules

I'm working on several extensions for an open source piece of software. Each of the extensions have files distributed through the file tree of the software that I am writing for. Initially, I created a Git project for one of those extensions, which worked great. Now though, I need to create Git repo's for the other extensions but cannot figure out how to do this. If I simply try to clone a project to my root workspace, this will overwrite my first Git repo.

Based on research, I think this can be done using sub-modules, however, all references to submodules seem to have each module in a different directory.

My question, is it possible to have several Git projects all housed in 1 directory using sub-modules?

Comment: Do you mean you want them all overlaid (which smparkes addresses), or that you want several of them in subdirectories of one directory (which is exactly what submodules are for)?

Answer (score 0):

No. Submodules aren't meant to be used to overlay repos.

The typical way to do this would be to create different branches for the individual extensions and then merge each branch into a master branch that represented the aggregation of all the extensions.

Answer (score 0):

The way I figured how to do this is as follows:

Clone a project into the root. Once it's working, rename the .git file to .git-%s, where %s represents 2 characters representing the project name. I then cloned another repo into the root and did the same. After doing this for all projects, I had the following 4 .git files in my root:

root
- .gitwp
- .gitbp
- .gitas
- .gitwps

I can now work on all projects at once. If I want to commit changes to a specific repo, I do the following:

mv .gitwp .git
git commit -m "Commit Message"
mv .git .gitwp

I hope this helps someone!